# "Access Denied" error for connecting to CloudSQL instance through Dataproc cluster even though credentials are correct

Tags: mysql, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a simple query through my dataproc cluster on my MySQL instance. Everything is on Google Cloud.

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop \
    --cluster=$cluster_name \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --class=org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop \
    --jars=$bucket/sqoop_jars/sqoop_sqoop-1.4.7.jar,$bucket/sqoop_jars/sqoop_avro-tools-1.8.2.jar,file:///usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar \
    -- \
    eval \
    -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true \
    --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
    --connect="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airports" \
    --username=root \
    --password-file=$pwd_file \
    --query "select count(*) from flights limit 10"
```

However, when I run it, the following error is returned:

> WARN tool.EvalSqlTool: SQL exception executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I assume this means my credentials are wrong. However, when I try to log into the instance directly with this command:

```sh
gcloud sql connect 'instance_name' --user=root
```

I log in with zero issues. There can't be anything wrong on the network layer at this point. I also tried creating different users and testing passwords and nothing works. Please help. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to CloudSQL instances from Datproc cluster you should use CloudSQL proxy: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy

Comment: Thank you but I already had that when I created the cluster. I assumed that if I didn't have it, it simply wouldn't connect at all, rather than give me an access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've specified a file for your password with `--password-file`. Do you also need to make this file available to the job with [`--files=`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/hadoop#--files)?

Comment: I haven't been able to test that out yet. I don't believe it's necessary but even when I just use ```--password=``` I'm not able to sign in, so I think there's something else wrong.

Comment: The other thing you can try is making sure root has `localhost` as an authorized Host - `CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'appPassword';` Although you should consider using a different user than root